# how many isomorphism are there from $Z_{12}$ to $Z_4\oplus Z_3$??

Tags: abstract-algebra

Isommorphism that maps identity elements of each group. But how to find the number of such isomorphism.

Comment: Only 1 question mark in the other.

Comment: @Dror And a capitalised "I", and properly pluralised "isomorphisms".

Comment: Stand corrected.